# iPhone sync problems in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, banshee, sync, rhythmbox, iphone

Since upgrading top 12.04, neither rhythmbox nor banshee can detect any of the songs on my iPhone3. Neither can sync with the iPhone either. Banshee just says "preparing to sync" for ever. Rhythmbox claims that there isn't enough room for the files (even if I only try to sync a playlist consisting of 1 file). Does anyone know why this is happening / how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've not yet attempted a sync with banshee or rhythmbox. However, out of the box, a clean install of 12.04 (x64) on a Dell XPS L502x with both Banshee and Rhythmbox produced the following results when connecting an iPhone4 via USB:

1. ubuntu detects the phone as both a Camera, and as a Music device
2. The music on the device is visible via both Rhythmbox and Banshee (I've not tried to update anything just yet - need to backup the phone first).
3. Shotwell cannot import photos - cannot obtain lock on device
4. Nautilus can browse the device and copy photos - nice workaround for shotwell

Side note: I'm finding that Banshee is now very resource hungry on this release. On 11.04 it was the better music player (especially if you had an apple device (prior to iphone 4).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the panel of complements of Rhythmbox and deactivate the "Apple support plugin", then disconect your iPhone and reconnect it.

Comment: I'm afraid that no such plugin is listed...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Spotify? I'm using it to sync music with my iphone (iOS 5).

http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/

[image]

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down. I know it is not an ideal solution but it is the easiest solution I have found to date and thought it worth sharing for those like me with an iPhone and no easy way to sync with it. Running iTunes in OSX or Windows in a virtual environment or rebooting to OSX or Windows are surely worse. What else is there?

Comment: I have posted a more detailed response to a similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/198866/iphone-4-ios-6-sync-with-ubuntu-12-04/235225#235225