# sync music with a iPhone 4 iOS 6

Tags: ios

Is there any way to sync an iPhone iOS 6 with my PC? I installed libimobiledevice and the iPhone is shown up in Rythmbox and Shotwell. But when i want to sync music with it, it doesn't work. There will be no music on my device. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

It is not yet possible to sync with devices on iOS 6.x.x.
In fact, libmobiledevice still does not support syncing with iOS 5.x.x

> If you are using iOS 5.x, the library that Rhythmbox (and others) use
>   to do this does not yet support the newer database version. If your
>   iOS device has recently been updated, then you simply need to wait for
>   libimobiledevice to be updated (watch the [website][1] under
>   Music/Video Synchronization Status for updates).
>     [1]: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

See here : [How to sync songs in Rhythmbox with an iPod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90027/how-to-sync-songs-in-rhythmbox-with-an-ipod)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Spotify? I'm using it to sync music with my iphone (iOS 5)...

http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/

[image]

Edited in response to Eliah Kagan's request below:

Follow the instructions at this link or as copied from it below:
http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/

1. Add this line to your list of repositories via the software settings dialogue

   ```
   deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
   ```
2. If you want to verify the downloaded packages, you will need to add our public key

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
   ```
3. Run apt-get update

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install spotify!

   ```
   sudo apt-get install spotify-client
   ```

Install the Spotify app via the iPhone app store on the iPhone and create a Spotify account (free).

Follow the instructions in Spotify to add your local music folder and then to connect your iPhone - briefly: open the spotify app in Ubuntu and on the iPhone, make sure you are signed in to your Spotify account on both devices and they should connect automatically over wifi. Sync music. Enjoy.

Currently the ogg format is not supported. I have added myself to the request for it here:

http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Local-file-support-OGG-Vorbis/idi-p/5451/page/2

Comment: This is not an answer to the question on *How can I sync with iOS 6.x.x*, since Spotify costs money and you can't sync any music you want.

Comment: @Alvar if you pay, I think you can sync music you already had… Still a good point.

Comment: @Andrew You can only sync music that exist in Spotify, you can't sync **any** music, I pay for it and I've tried.

Comment: I have not yet paid for it but I am able to sync music I have ripped from CD myself (asunder) which I think fairly comes under the heading of "any music" and my answer was in the form of a question because I've not yet _upgraded_ to iOS 6 so can not confirm that it works. I thought it worth a suggestion in case it was of help to you or others like me, who have an iPhone (for whatever reason) and would like to sync music with it.

Comment: @user104140 You should edit this answer so it explains *how* to  use Spotify for this purpose. Right now, this only marginally answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an app that allows you to put music on your phone. I don't think you can "sync" it (as in downloading music FROM the phone), but you can definitely put transfer music from any Linux computer onto an iPhone 4s.

The app is called "EZMP3 Player. It uses a web interface so you transfer files over the network. Once you download the app it provides you with a wi-fi and 3G IP address. You then point your browser on your computer at it and you will be presented with a page that you can select audio files to transfer to your phone.

You have to use the app to play the music but the player is fully featured (it plays music with the screen locked, you can skip tracks, etc..).

This is the only feasible solution that worked for me ( after spending days messing with Windows on VirtualBox, RhythmBox, Amarog, GPodder, etc..).

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 box.